# Magento 2 admin panel working great on my Chrome browser but giving 'connection timeout error' on Firefox

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

Since yesterday I'm not able to open Magento 2 admin panel on my Firefox browser as I used to do. I don't remember making any changes which would cause something like this. After so much of debugging and no success, when I tried to open it on Chrome browser then it was working fine like before.

> **Magento admin panel on Firefox:**
> [image: Firefox Screenshot]

> **Magento admin panel on Chrome:**
> [image: Chrome screenshot]

Comment: Strange issue. Can you also check on Firefox private window and Chrome incognito if the results are the same with these?

Comment: These results are from private window only from both the browsers @GerarddeVisser

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache in chrome including cookies and images and try again